# Function is not returning anything

Tags: javascript, html

I hava a function, when I run in the console it runs fine, but doesn't run from html file.

**HTML file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>func1</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='func1.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>FUNC 1</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Js File:**

```
function factorial(x){
    var y=1;
    while(x>0){
        y=y*x
        x=x-1;
    }
    return y;
}

factorial(3);
```

I see nothing in the console. WHY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not seeing anything in the console because you're not actually *logging* anything to the console.

You need to use `console.log(factorial(3))` if you want to see the result of the function.

The only reason you see a result when you run the above code directly in the console is because the console outputs the result of each expression it evaluates. This only applies to things actually *inputted* into the console, not to all arbitrary JavaScript that runs in your browser.

Comment: Thank you very much, my bad haven't noticed.